# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.5 in auth of custom guard

Tags: php, laravel

While trying to authenticate with custom guard throws me an error Trying to get property of non-object in Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

my RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch($guard){
        case 'delimin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('delimin.dashboard');
            }
            break;

        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
        }
            break;
    }


    return $next($request);
}
```

Error showing in VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
 protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
{
    $config = config('session');

    $response->headers->setCookie(
        new Cookie(
            'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
            $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
        )
    );

    return $response;
}
```

It never redirects to intented page. Always $this->middleware('auth:guard_name'); retrun false.
I am stuck with this for the last two days. Please help me to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to custom primary key associated with the model of custom guard. I changed it to id itself and it worked!